# Turning off merges in Lucene with sequential segmets of fixed size

Tags: lucene, sequential

Is it possible to tell a Lucene to write its segments sequentially and of fixed size? By this way we would avoid merges which are heavy for large segments. Lucene has LogMergePolicy classes with similar functionality which gives ability to set max segment size by doc count or file size, but it is just a limit for merges.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [NRTCachingDirectory](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/NRTCachingDirectory.html) to do the small segment merges in memory and only write them out to disk once they reach ~256MiB or so.

But fundamentally the merges are necessary since the data structures like the FST are write-once and are modified by creating a new one.

Maybe this can be combined with the [NoMergePolicy](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/NoMergePolicy.html) for the FilesystemDirectory it will not perform further merges. But that will have pretty bad query performance.

Maybe do merges manually and somehow merge them all at once (by setting TieredMergePolicy.setMaxMergeAtOnceExplicit())

But Merging is just a cost of doing business, probably better to get used to it and tune the MergePolicy to your workload.

Comment: Writing segments to RAM is not an option for me due to data loss possibility. In my case data are logs that never change, so avoiding merges would be performance improvement.